# Turn off field programmatically in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, arcobjects, arcmap

I'm creating an addin button in Arcmap via VB.net that when clicked, runs the identify tool. But I want only selected fields to appear in the identify dialog. I thought of hiding the unnecessary fields and then showing them again after the button is used.

Does anyone know how to programmatically turn off/on field?

Comment: You mean, them being invisible, or just still there but not clickable ?

Comment: Yes I just want the fields to be invisible. I would like them to be visible again after using the button(i think by turning all fields on,just like what can be done with the attribute table of a layer).

Comment: use textfield1.visible = false to hide the textfield

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't mean textfield. I am referring to fields or columns of an attribute table for a feature class or shapefile in ArcMap.

Comment: Use gis.stackexchange.com to find people that know what you are talking about.

Comment: I think you'll actually need to customise the Identify tool, rather than trying to hide fields. There's an old VB6 sample that might be portable to .Net:
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/Samples/Controls/Commands/Identify/Identify.htm

Comment: @Juffy, I've already run through the codes in that link. But I have no idea how to use the sample code or make it work. I am new to ArcMap customization and what I know is how to create and deploy an addin.I hope someone could enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

you have to iterate the fields in layer and then set visible property into false .
see this link in

[gis.stackExchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41752/turn-off-field-programmatically-in-arcmap-via-vb-net)